# Lotus Notes: Printing Footer on each page

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a basic requirement of printing a Lotus Notes form (it can be a long form depending upon the data filled in the field) and each page should contain a Footer. Footer is very large approx > 256 characters, but the Footer property of the form (6th tab of Form properties) doesn't allow more than 255 characters.

I have tried giving the footer in the "Window title" and using &W in the Footer tab of the Form properties, but the Window title is only taking 1st line of the sentence.

Can someone tell how to get this much big footer in every page and print also.

Comment: header/footer is part of form design (item $Header), I would recommend you to look into DXL nd try to find out if you can change item '$header', otherwise I think its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use a 3rd party tool to produce output. Some candidates: Notes2Paper, Swing, IntelliPrint